# Increment Memory Usage in SQL CLR

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, clr

To get the total memory used by SQL CLR, you would run the following query:

```
select single_pages_kb + multi_pages_kb + virtual_memory_committed_kb from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks where type = 'MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR'
```

The result I am getting is:
[image]

Is there any way to increment this memory? If so How, besides buying more RAM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on personal--if not overly informed--experience, I'm pretty certain you (aka the "outside user") cannot control how much memory SQL allocates to CLR processes.

Further information that may or may not help here: there are limts, ratios, and (our big headache) fragmentation of memory assigned over time (that's days of regular use). Our issues could only address by stopping and restarting the SQL service. Again, I'm pretty certain that it doesn't matter how much memory is available on the box, so much as the internal means by which SQL addresses and allocates it. The problems that we were having back when were tangled, confused, recurrent, and very irritating... and then, based on my research, we upgraded to 64-bit edition (SQL 2008), which has very different means of addressing and allocating all that memory we had installed on the box. All of our problems went away, and I haven't had to consider the situation ever since.